# Faking Oracle statistics?

Tags: performance, oracle

Is there a way to force the Oracle too "see" a table and associated indexes as being bigger than they really are?

In other words, is there a way to "fake" database statistics, so the cost based optimizer would make decisions on a nearly-empty database, that are closer to decisions that would be made in a real, big production database?

The idea is to be able to experiment (vis-a-vis execution plan) with various indexing / querying / (de)normalization strategies very early in the database design process, without wasting time writing code that fills it with representative test data (most of which will end-up being discarded anyway, since the database design is still not settled).

Importing statistics is out of question, since the production database does not even exist yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  The `DBMS_STATS` package has a number of procedures that allow you to force statistics on objects.  There are [dbms_stats.set_table_stats](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i997763) and [dbms_stats.set_index_stats](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_stats.htm#i997579) procedures, for example.